# Diferencia entre const y variables inmutables en Rust

Tags: rust, constantes, inmutabilidad

Dado que las variables en rust son inmutables por defecto. ¿Porqué existe el concepto de const en el lenguaje?¿Hay alguna diferencia efectiva?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37877381/13419694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque a priori puedan parecer que son casi la misma cosa realmente tiene diferencias clave, usos distintos y razones propias que justifican la existencia de ambas.

Quizás sea más difícil ver las diferencias de `const` con respecto a `static` (no mutable) que con respecto a las variables.

### Palabras clave

Obviamente la primera diferencia es que se usan distintas plabras clave para declararlas:

- **Variables:** `let`).
- **Items estáticos:** `static`
- **Constantes:** `const`.

### Mutabilidad

- **Variable:** inmutable por defecto pero puede opcionalmente marcarse como mutable mediante `mut`.
- **static:** igual que las variables.
- **const:** una constante es siempre inmutable.

### Inferencia de tipos

- **Variable:** indicar el tipo al declararla es en general opcional. El compilador es capaz de inferir automáticamente el tipo:

  ```
  let foo = 7;      // Válido. Inferencia de tipos.
  let foo: i8 = 7;  // Válido
  ```
- **static:** es obligatorio indicar el tipo.

  ```
  static FOO: i8 = 7; // Válido
  static FOO = 7;     // Error
  ```
- **const:** es obligatorio indicar el tipo.

  ```
  const FOO: i8 = 7; // Válido
  const FOO = 7;     // Error
  ```

### Tiempo de evaluación del valor asignado

Una de las diferencias más trascendentales de las constantes es cuando se calcula el valor de la misma.

- **Variable:** puede evaluarse en tiempo de ejecución, por lo que, por ejemplo,se le puede asignar el retorno de una función no constante:

  ```
  fn square(n: i64) -> i64 {
      n * n
  }

  fn main() {
      let num = square(7);
  }
  ```
- **const:** el valor de una constante se calcula siempre en tiempo de compilación, por tanto su inicializador debe ser siempre una [expresión constante](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html#constant-expressions). Esto restringe su asignación a cosas que el compilador puede calcular en tiempo de compilación, como literales, llamadas a funciones constantes, tuple structs, etc

  ```
  const NUM: f64 = square(7); // Error
  ```

  No obstante, esta diferencia hace que podamos usar una constante en sitios donde no podemos usar una variable, por ejemplo podemos usar una constante para especificar la longitud de un array.
- **static:** igual que las constantes.

### Cómo se almacenan

- **Variables:** una variable (mutables o inmutables) está asociada a un valor almacenado en memoria, con una dirección de memoria conocida, representativa y estable. Esto implica que podemos obtener referencias a ese valor en memoria con seguridad. El compilador luego fuerza "artificialmente" la inmutabilidad si no se hace uso de `mut`.
- **static:** se comportan como las variables en este aspecto.
- **const:** una constante en cambio solo representan un valor y no tienen una localización de memoria especifica asociada.

  En general el valor de la constante se inserta directamente en el código en cada sitio que es necesitado, lo que se conoce como "inlined". El compilador aquí tiene cierta libertad a la hora de tratar la constante en cada caso concreto con la finalidad de optimizar todo lo posible el código resultante, para constantes más complejas se puede almacenar en memoria de solo lectura y referenciar desde ahí en los lugares donde se necesita acceder a la constante.

  Esto implica que no se garantiza que exista un valor en la pila asociado a la constante, o que solo exista una instancia del mismo.

Puedes por tanto obtener referencias a items variables o estáticos (incluso puedes mutarlos), pero no puedes hacer esto con constantes. Esta es quizás la diferencia más significativa entre `(inmutable)static` y `const`.

Como resultado de todo esto, en general el uso de constantes suele dar como resultado un ejecutable más pesado pero un mejor desempeño en tiempo de ejecución, obviamente hay excepciones, especialmente si la constante no es un "valor simple" como un entero, donde ya dependemos de las optimizaciones del compilador y lo bien que se ajuste a nuestro caso concreto.

### Ámbito

- **Variables:** no pueden definirse en el ámbito global.
- **static:** puede definirse en cualquier ámbito, incluido el global.
- **const:** puede definirse en cualquier ámbito, incluido el global.

Una gran diferencia entre las constantes/ítems estáticos y las variables es que las primeras pueden ser declaradas en cualquier ámbito. Eso incluye el ámbito global, estando disponibles en cualquier ámbito y durante todo el tiempo de ejecución del programa:

```
const PI: f32 = 3.14159; // Correcto
let pi = 3.141459;       // Error de compilación

fn main() {

}
```

### Shadowing

- **Variable:** el *shadowing* está permitido:
- **static:** no se permite el *shadowing* (en el mismo ámbito).
- **const:** no se permite el *shadowing* (en el mismo ámbito).

Rust permite declarar una variable con el mismo nombre, incluso en el mismo ámbito. La nueva variable tiene su propio valor y su región de memoria independiente de la anterior, simplemente solapa a la variable previamente definida. A esto se le conoce como shadowing (sombreado). En cambio no se puede hacer esto con static/const:

```
  fn main() {
      let a: i8 = 6;
      let a: i8 = 13;     // Correcto    
      static a: i8 = 13;  // Error
      const a: 18 = 13;   // Error

      static NUM: i8 = 7;
      static NUM: i8 = 3; // Error
      const NUM: i8 = 3;  // Error
      let NUM: i8 = 3;    // Error
  }
```

### Propiedad

La propiedad de un valor que pertenece a una variable puede ser movida a otra variable y por tanto dejar de estar la primera disponible:

```
fn main() {
    let foo = String::from("Hola");
    let bar = foo;
    println!("{foo}"); // Error
}
```

esto no es posible con las constantes.

---

Como norma general, si tienes un valor que no cambia en todo el programa y conocido en tiempo de compilación, usa `const`.

`static` tiene menos casos de uso, debe reservarse para situaciones en las que `const` no es válida por alguna razón concreta, como que necesitemos mutar el valor o usar referencias al mismo. Un caso común es acceder a librerías de rust desde C mediante FFI, donde es posible acceder a un elemento global público estático pero no a una constante.

Enlaces de interés:

- Rust Book: [Variables and mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html)
- Rust Doc: [`static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.static.html) y [`const`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.const.html) keywords.
- Rust RFCS: [const-vs-static (RFC 246)](https://htmlhttps://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0246-const-vs-static.html)